# Select prepared-statement row count

Tags: sql, vb.net, prepared-statement

I may be late to the game here but I am forcing myself into prepared statments for reasons everybody is aware of by now for future development. Thankfully it's been smooth sailing so far! However, i am having a hard time with the following.  Below is my VB.NET code snippet:

```
Dim strConnect As String = "server!"  
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim cn as SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnect)

Dim str As String = ""
Dim row As SqlDataReader 
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT top 10 TypeOfDeliciousPie FROM FamilyLuncheon WHERE MomsSecretSauce  like '%' + @sstring + '%'", cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sstring", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sstring
cn.Open()
row = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While row.Read()
    str += """" + row(TypeOfDeliciousPie ) + ""","
End While
cn.close()
```

Now, the problem I am having is I need a count of total rows prior to looping though the dataset. In short, I'm building a simple json string manually with the returned data and for the jquery to work properly, I need a total row count.

How best should I go about getting a total row count from a `SELECT` prepared statement? Before I could simply load it into a datatable and simply `table.Rows.count` but I can't seem to find something similar. My apologizes if this has previously been covered. I've searched here and google for a proper solution for the past couple hours.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a `DataTable` when using a `SqlCommand` for the query, either using a [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1.aspx), or using [`DataTable.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx), e.g.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

And then use `dt.Rows.Count` like you are used to.

Comment: Thanks Mark! In attempting to resolved this myself, I tried to load a Datatable but failed.   This actually makes existing code easier to convert to prepared statements as most of that code is all using datatables to populate the website. I will only have to make minor edits.  Really appreciate you help!